# Primefaces printer print div

Tags: printing, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to print one div with primefaces printer (primefaces 3.2 with myfaces 2.0).

My faces code is like:

```
            <div id="page">
                <!-- SIDEBAR -->
                <div id="sidebar"
                    class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-shadow sidebar">
                    <ui:insert name="sidebar"></ui:insert>
                    <p:commandButton value="Print" type="button">
                        <p:printer target="content" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>

                <!-- CONTENT -->
                <div id="content">
                        <ui:insert name="content">...</ui:insert>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
```

But I get a FacesException:

```
 javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component content in view.
```

Is this possible with primefaces printer or is there another way to do this.

Best Regards Veote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p:printer` expects an id of the component, but `ui:insert` defines a logical section which is going to be inserted by the client. You could try to wrap the content you wish to print in `p:outputPanel` like so:

```
<p:outputPanel id="content">
  <ui:insert name="content" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Ok this works, thanks. But I cant print charts :/ Do you know a way how to print primefaces charts with primefaces printer?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by `charts` but I suggest you to ask this in a new question and post the code for `charts` that you're trying to print.